# How to wrap text around a figure?

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

How to wrap text around a figure in LaTeX like this?

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aenean quis mi ut elit interdum imperdiet quis non ante.
Sed imperdiet, sapien quis    +------------------------+
viverra rhoncus, tellus dui   |                        |
dictum nisl, at porta purus   |                        |
ipsum ac turpis. Fusce auctor |         FIGURE         |
ullamcorper adipiscing. Nunc  |          HERE          |
non quam ac orci egestas con- |                        |
sequat ut eget quam. Cras     |                        |
blandit condimentum ornare.   +------------------------+
Curabitur aliquam, nulla sit amet iaculis tristique, mi
nulla auctor magna, sit amet imperdiet ante arcu a libero.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the [wrapfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package. The documentation in the `.sty` file itself says:

> The "wrapfigure" and "wraptable" environments interact
>   properly with the "\caption" command to produce proper numbering, but
>   they are not regular floats like "figure" and "table", so (beware!) they
>   may be printed out of sequence with the regular floats.

Comment: +1.  Wrapfig is the answer here, but note that it's happiest in the case the OP illustrated, of figures contained in a body of paragraph text.  It (more or less unavoidably) tends to become less happy near lists, equations and the like, and I recall it needing some help near page-breaks.  Short version: it does its job well, but don't obsess about the layout until nearly the final version of your document.

Comment: @Norman "...but don't obsess about the layout until nearly the final version of your document" -- that's good advice for any *TeXed doc!

Comment: \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{1in}
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{<your.eps>}
 \noindent \hrulefill
\end{wrapfigure}
\input{<yourtext>} %% that's how I had it working for a left-floating picture.

Answer (score 5):

The [floatflt](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatflt) package is another approach to wrap text around floats.

Comment: I've only made light use of wrapfig and didn't know of floatfit. Do you prefer one to the other? Any reasons that would fit into a comment?

Comment: floatflt has a none-free license: http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/licenses.other-nonfree.html therefore it's not included in some TeX distributions (for instance TeX Live, Debian and Ubuntu repositories). I prefer wrapfig (newer, free, usually pre-installed, many options).

Answer (score 3):

Another package I have used for this purpose is the [picins](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/) package. I believe that both wrapfig and picins package have problems when used inside a list environments.  They tend to mess up indents. I used to work around it by ending the list right after the item containing the figure, and starting a new list right away.

If you can, you may want to use ConTeXt instead.

Comment: What would you write to do this in ConTeXt?

Comment: @Will You would use `\placefigure`.  Documentation is at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Floating_Objects

Answer (score 3):

Place `\usepackage{wrapfig}` into the preamble.

This will take care of figure placement and also tables if you require that.
The different commands being `\begin{wrapfigure}` and `\begin{wraptable}` with the obvious associated endings to close, and `\includegraphics` between for specification.

Place the image or table at the beginning of the paragraph and I find that simply creating an empty line works better for the wrap than `\paragraph{}`, on the paragraph immediately before.

Use either scale *or* width, height. Not both.