# Absolute positioning of wrapfig

Tags: floats, positioning, wrapfigure

In Microsoft Word, it is common to create a floating text box, separate from the normal body text, that can be placed anywhere on the page. The body text will then wrap around this text box so everything is readable.

In (La)TeX, the `wrapfigure` package allows figures to be created that the body text will wrap around, but they may only be placed at the beginning of paragraphs and on the edges of the page. The package doesn't seem to allow *absolute* placement independent of the body text and margins. Using the absolute-placement package `textpos` in conjunction with `wrapfig` will simply break the wrapping.

So how can I have the best of both worlds—text wrapping and absolute placement (at the very least, vertical placement)?

Something like the diagram in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291/1517), or [this image from Word](http://www.zurb.com/blog_uploads/0000/0210/ms-word-2007-text-wrap.gif).

(Edited for generality and clarity.)

Comment: I see, and then the idea is that on each page, the figure occurs, say, 2.5" down from the top?

Comment: @Antal - That is correct.

Comment: I think you may be forced to adjust each figure individually.

Comment: Even with setting each box's position individually, is doing so still possible while keeping the wrapping? (Although I bet I can set them all at once by creating a custom command for them.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Placing a picture somewhere on the page is easy. The problem is the wrapping. It is easy to say "indent line 5-10 of the next **paragraph**". But due to the asynchronic page builder there is in tex no way (unless your document is very simple) to say "indent line 5-10 of the next **page**". Perhaps it is possible with luatex. But with pdflatex you will have to do it manually. See also on CTAN wrapfig/multiple-span.txt.

Comment: [multiple-span.txt](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt) (putting this here for my own purposes)

Comment: So maybe this is another instance where TeX being Turing complete is of no help? Having to follow the instructions in multiple-span.txt is a real nuisance.

Comment: @Hendrik — To do this in TeX would require you to hook into `\everypar` from the very beginning of the text, measure each paragraph before it's set, and keep track of where you are on the page at the end of every paragraph. (Perhaps using the output routine, but not necessarily; see vwcol for an example of all this.) *Possible*, and easier if you can assume paragraph text only, but this hasn't been implemented in any format or package that I'm aware of. Messy business indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest for you to dive into `tikz` manual. If you can use `pdflatex` and produce pdf directly, you can do absolute page placements with tikz, and later just do the usual `includegraphics` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Tikz, it's fantastic. I've gotten the text boxes styled exactly how I want with it. But I'm still unable to figure out how to get text to wrap around tikzpictures while using absolute positioning; I wind up with overlapping text.