# Creating multiple columns of different width

Tags: columns, geometry, width

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and am using it to write an exam. I'm using the `geometry` package to create two columns. I'd like one column to be 5" and the second column to be 1" with 0.5" separating the columns and 1" for the left and right margins. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change \hsize in the middle of a paragraph at pagebreak, especially for two-column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11166/how-to-change-hsize-in-the-middle-of-a-paragraph-at-pagebreak-especially-for-tw)

Comment: @Leo: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. The OP doesn't want to change \hsize in the middle of a paragraph here.

Comment: @Martin: Maybe. Generally speaking, it is needed. For some simple applications, `\marginpar`, or `minipage`, or `fancyhdr` with some drawing tricks can solve the problem. It depends.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't want the real two-column document of different width, in which a free text stream can be used.

If you may break the columns manually, [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package is powerful enough.