# Text-wrapping around image at top of page

Tags: floats, positioning, wrapfigure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute positioning of wrapfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/absolute-positioning-of-wrapfig)

I want to insert an image in a LaTeX document so that it is always positioned at the top of the page and the text flows around it.

I'm aware of `wrapfig` (and one or two similar packages) which do text wrapping - but, as far as I can tell, one can't force these packages to place the image at the top of the page.

I'm sure someone must have encountered this problem before (as images look better when placed at the top), but I've been unable to find any solutions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Hmmm... May sound trivial, but have you tried `\begin{figure}[t!]`?

Comment: Unfortunately this may not be as easy as it seems it should be - see the discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4269/6984 (which is a more general version of the same problem).

Comment: @CountZero: It's about a wrapping figure not a normal one. (However, simply using a normal figure would be IMHO anyway better)

Comment: Unfortunately my idea to use `\afterpage` doesn't work. The `wrapfigure` then doesn't connect with the next paragraph and is pushed to the end of the document.

Comment: Re-reading the question in the link given by Ant, I think that the present question is a duplicate.