# How to wrap text around a figure? (revised)

Tags: positioning, line-breaking, paragraphs, wrapfigure, picins

This question has been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-figure) (and in fact I stole the diagram below from that question) but the answers are not sufficient for my needs (at least near as I can tell).

What I want is the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aenean quis mi ut elit interdum imperdiet quis non ante.
Sed imperdiet, sapien quis    +------------------------+
viverra rhoncus, tellus dui   |                        |
dictum nisl, at porta purus   |                        |
ipsum ac turpis. Fusce auctor |         FIGURE         |
ullamcorper adipiscing. Nunc  |          HERE          |
non quam ac orci egestas con- |                        |
sequat ut eget quam. Cras     |                        |
blandit condimentum ornare.   +------------------------+
Curabitur aliquam, nulla sit amet iaculis tristique, mi
nulla auctor magna, sit amet imperdiet ante arcu a libero.
```

However, I do *not* want the "figure here" bit to start at the top of the paragraph. I've played around with `wrapfig` and `picins` and looked at the documentation for `floatflt`, and haven't really found anything. (`wrapfig` seems to always put it at the top, `floatflt` doesn't have any options for that sort of placement, and `picins` appears to start a new paragraph.)

Is there any way to do it besides render the document without the figure, look where the line break is, force a line break at that point, start a new paragraph, and `\noindent`? As much as I enjoy doing that sort of thing and think it falls right in line with TeX's philosophy of "don't worry about layout specifics", ideally that wouldn't apply here. Also ideal is if it can figure out how big the figure is, instead of me telling it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the [cutwin](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/cutwin/) package. Here's an MWE (Minimum Working Example) that demonstrates how it might be used in practice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cutwin,lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\opencutright
\begin{document}

% Define contents of "cutout window" before starting
%   the cutout environment. For this MWE, use a
%   "dummy" image (a black rectangle).
\def\windowpagestuff{\flushright 
   \includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{DummyFileName}}

% Set the cutout to start after 3 lines of text
%   and to have a height of 8 lines; width of
%   this cutout: 0.5\textwidth .
\begin{cutout}{3}{0.5\textwidth}{0pt}{8}
     \noindent
     \lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I've loaded the `graphicx` package with the `demo` option, which allows me to load a "dummy" graphics file. In actual practice, one would omit the `demo` option and load a "real" graphics file.

**Addendum** If the paragraph in question is located close to a page break, things may become a bit unpredictable. When in doubt, you could "encase" the `cutout` environment in a pair of `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` and `\end{minipage}` statements.

Comment: I used to also use `\rule` but then discovered that with `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`,  you can simply use `\includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{imageFileName}`. Just an FYI.

Comment: Great, thanks! It's too bad that (it seems) Latex has no way of doing this without specifying the actual size of stuff. (You might actually be able to do something with putting the window contents into a box and then using settobox and the calc package or something... but I think I'm too lazy.)

Comment: @EvanED: I suspect that once you start playing with cutouts and other non-rectangular paragraph shapes -- while keeping the font size fixed -- there's probably no general method for automating the calculations of the size of the cutout, the size of the image, etc. I suspect it's a case of either too many free parameters (no unique solution) or not enough free parameters (so that the even the existence of a solution might not be fulfilled except as a fluke).

Comment: @Mico: It is not a case of too may free parameters: ConTeXt does the calculations in terms of number of lines using `\placefigure[right,hanging,3*lines,none]{}{...}`

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've modified the MWE to make use of your suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

The `\parshape` primitive of TeX allows you to specify the paragraph shape on a line-by-line basis using an `<indent> <width>` pair. Why include this approach when Mico already did such a nice and clean approach via [`cutwin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cutwin)? Well, using `\parshape` allows you to typeset arbitrary (non-rectilinear) shapes as well, making it useful to understand how it works.

The following example is a crude reproduction of `cutwin` using `\parshape` and requires some manual intervention. It won't work well close to page breaks, but the same holds for `wrapfig` and friends.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
% The 'demo' option creates a 150pt x 100pt black rectangle by default
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et nunc id sem dictum ullamcorper 
ut vitae augue. Etiam vehicula, dolor sit amet eleifend imperdiet, tortor neque mollis dui, ut 
laoreet neque lectus a metus. Vivamus fermentum, tellus eget cursus mollis, mi orci facilisis lacus, 
vitae aliquet arcu est nec tortor. Integer ut nunc vulputate velit dapibus sodales eget eu nulla. 
Duis mattis tristique justo semper condimentum. Phasellus eu libero odio. Integer interdum turpis in 
metus rhoncus ac tempus tortor fermentum.

% Image inclusion
\newlength{\figwidth}%
\setlength{\figwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-150pt-2ex\relax}
\null\hfill\smash{\raisebox{-\dimexpr 9.5\baselineskip+\parskip\relax}%
  {\includegraphics{image}}}\strut \\[-\dimexpr 3\baselineskip+2\parskip\relax]

% Paragraph formatting
\parshape=13 % 13 lines will be adjusted
0pt \linewidth 0pt \linewidth % 2 lines are regular
0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth
0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth 0pt \figwidth % 10 lines are indented on right
0pt \linewidth % last line resets the paragraph alignment to regular
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et nunc id sem dictum ullamcorper 
ut vitae augue. Etiam vehicula, dolor sit amet eleifend imperdiet, tortor neque mollis dui, ut 
laoreet neque lectus a metus. Vivamus fermentum, tellus eget cursus mollis, mi orci facilisis lacus, 
vitae aliquet arcu est nec tortor. Integer ut nunc vulputate velit dapibus sodales eget eu nulla. 
Duis mattis tristique justo semper condimentum. Phasellus eu libero odio. Integer interdum turpis in 
metus rhoncus ac tempus tortor fermentum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et nunc id sem dictum ullamcorper 
ut vitae augue. Etiam vehicula, dolor sit amet eleifend imperdiet, tortor neque mollis dui, ut 
laoreet neque lectus a metus. Vivamus fermentum, tellus eget cursus mollis, mi orci facilisis lacus, 
vitae aliquet arcu est nec tortor. Integer ut nunc vulputate velit dapibus sodales eget eu nulla. 
Duis mattis tristique justo semper condimentum. Phasellus eu libero odio. Integer interdum turpis in 
metus rhoncus ac tempus tortor fermentum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et nunc id sem dictum ullamcorper 
ut vitae augue. Etiam vehicula, dolor sit amet eleifend imperdiet, tortor neque mollis dui, ut 
laoreet neque lectus a metus. Vivamus fermentum, tellus eget cursus mollis, mi orci facilisis lacus, 
vitae aliquet arcu est nec tortor. Integer ut nunc vulputate velit dapibus sodales eget eu nulla. 
Duis mattis tristique justo semper condimentum. Phasellus eu libero odio. Integer interdum turpis in 
metus rhoncus ac tempus tortor fermentum.

\end{document}​
```

`\parshape=<n> <i1> <l1> <i2> <l2> ...` sets the line `i`ndents and `l`ine widths for the following `<n>` lines in a paragraph. If the paragraph continues past `<n>` lines, it uses the last set `<i> <l>` pair.

So, in the above MWE, the image is first set, followed by the paragraph:

- Image: `image` is typeset flush right and `\smash`ed, and dropped (via `\raisebox`) into position. A manual calculation of the number of lines depends on the image height. In my example, the image is dropped `9.5\baselineskip+\parskip`. The vertical back-skip/correction after setting the image is needed so that prior paragraphs line up.
- Paragraph: The first two lines (out of `13`) is indented `0pt` and has a width of `\linewidth`. The next 10 lines have a width of `\figwidth`, set to `\linewidth-150pt-2ex` which leaves a `2ex` gap between the paragraph text and image. The last (13th) line resets the paragraph style back to no indent (`0pt`) and natural width (`\linewidth`), just like the first two lines.

As mentioned, now it would be possible to modify this approach to accommodate images or shapes that are irregular.

Comment: `cutwin` also allows "shaped cutouts", but understanding the construction via `\parshape` might be just as useful.

Comment: AFAIS, `cutwin` *has* to use `\parshape` under the hood.

Comment: Many thanks for this great explanation of how to use the TeX "primitive" command `\parshape`!

Comment: @morbusg: That is correct.

Comment: How do you calculate the length used in `\\[-\dimexpr 3\baselineskip+2\parskip\relax]`? Does that depend one the picture or not?

Comment: @Gaussler: It has to do with the fact that you're inserting the image in a separate *paragraph* above the one being manipulated with `\parshape`. It therefore involves some skip relative to `\baselineskip` and `\parskip`. Not exactly sure how I came up with the combination though...

Answer (score 6):

See also the old but still useful `picinpar` package from LaTeX 2.09 times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{window}[2,r,\rule{4cm}{3cm},]
\lipsum[1]
\end{window}

\end{document}
```

[image]