# Paragraph indentation incorrect with picinpar package

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, picinpar

I am using the `picinpar` package and don't know why the paragraph indentation is not working.   The problem words are highlighted:

[image]

### Notes:

- I am not stuck to using the `picinpar` package, but want to *avoid* having to specify the width of the figure at the point it is inserted.  The example provided uses `\includegraphics` to keep the MWE simpler, but my figures are `tikz` figures so I use `\input` instead of ``\includegraphics`in my real use case.
  I tried the other solutions at the references question, and found`picinpar` the easiest to use.
- I thought perhaps the problem was that `\parskip` and `\parindent` were being rest within the `window` environment as in [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/why-is-parskip-zero-inside-a-minipage), but that solution (commented out) had no effect.
- This work fine if the `parskip` pacakge is used, but I am trying to have the recommended indented paragraphs.

### References:

- [How to wrap text around a figure? (revised).](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40998/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{parskip}% Works great with this.
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}% To highlight problem text

\newlength{\currentparskip}
\newlength{\currentparindent}
\newcommand{\MyWrapFig}[3][]{%
    % #1 = options: number of lines, align
    % #2= figure content
    % #3= text content
    %
    %\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value
    %\setlength{\currentparindent}{\parindent}% save the value
    %
    \begin{window}[#1, #2,]
        %\setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
        %\setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}% restore the value
        #3%
    \end{window}
}%

\newcommand{\SomeMoreText}{Some text. Some more text.}%
\newcommand{\Text}{%
    \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText
    \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText
}%


\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\MyWrapFig[1,r]{%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{MyFigure}
}{%
    \textcolor{red}{Here} is a paragraph that should \emph{not} be indented without parskip.
    \SomeMoreText

    \textcolor{red}{This} is the second paragraph which \emph{should} be indented without parskip.
    \SomeMoreText \SomeMoreText \SomeMoreText

    \textcolor{red}{Last} paragraph that \emph{should} also be indented without parskip.
    \Text
}

\MyWrapFig[1,r]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{MyFigure}
}{%
    Here is a paragraph that should be indented without parskip.
    \SomeMoreText

    \textcolor{red}{This} is the second paragraph which \emph{should} be indented without parskip.
    \SomeMoreText

    \textcolor{red}{Last} paragraph that \emph{should} also be indented without parskip.
    \Text
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: picinpar is a latex 2.09 package; it's remarkable that it works at all, broken results or not.  note that the catalogue entry for it says “Users should note that Piet van Oostrum (in a published review of packages of this sort) does not recommend this package; picins is recommended instead.”

Comment: @wasteofspace Do you want to write up an answer here?

Comment: @Johannes_B `picins` is also a 2.09 package, isn't it? (And the licence prevents distribution so it is not in TL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but perhaps it is helpful. What it does achieve:

- paragraphs which should be indented are indented automatically;
- you do not need to specify the width of the inserted thing.

What it does not achieve:

- the first paragraph following a sectional division must be marked with `\noindent` if it is to be wrapped around an inserted thing;

There was a problem with some words overspilling, creating overfull boxes. Thanks to [Peter Grill's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119478/paragraph-indentation-incorrect-with-picinpar-package/253733?noredirect=1#comment606652_253733) for noting that the power of `microtype` solves this.

With the addition of `\noindent`, I get this output automatically:

[image: flowed text around inserted things]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}% To highlight problem text
\newcommand{\SomeMoreText}{Some text. Some more text.}%
\newcommand{\Text}{%
    \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText
    \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText   \SomeMoreText
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
  \section{First Section}
  \InsertBoxR{1}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{MyFigure}}
  \noindent\textcolor{red}{Here} is a paragraph that should \emph{not} be indented without parskip.
  \SomeMoreText

  \textcolor{red}{This} is the second paragraph which \emph{should} be indented without parskip.
  \SomeMoreText \SomeMoreText \SomeMoreText

  \textcolor{red}{Last} paragraph that \emph{should} also be indented without parskip.
  \Text

  \InsertBoxR{1}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{MyFigure}}
  Here is a paragraph that should be indented without parskip.
  \SomeMoreText

  \textcolor{red}{This} is the second paragraph which \emph{should} be indented without parskip.
  \SomeMoreText

  \textcolor{red}{Last} paragraph that \emph{should} also be indented without parskip.
  \Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: dammit! All the pictures have disappeared again even ones which displayed fine a second ago.

Comment: `insbox` looks promising.

Comment: @PeterGrill Do you have any idea how to solve the problem with the 'should'? I mean, other than by hand.

Comment: If you referring to the indentation of the first para, I don't know how to automate that.

Comment: @PeterGrill I meant more the fact that the emphasised 'should' isn't pushed to the next line.

Comment: Using `\usepackage{microtype}` seems to take care of that just fine.

Comment: @PeterGrill Excellent! Thank you. Edited accordingly. I have no ideas about the `\noindent`. You could always adopt British style and use `indentfirst` for consistency. (I'm not sure it is 'British' style but it seems to tend that way.)

Comment: Not related to italic correction as same problem occurs if you replace  `\emph{should}` with `should`. Luckily, `microtype` fixes both cases.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks. I meant to check but, at the time, I was sleepy. Corrected. I don't know why I didn't remember to check when I edited.