# How do I write something beside math text?

Tags: formatting

I have some giant matrices or systems of equations that are getting in my way of my text. Basically is hard enough to write them all in the same line, but when I want to write something beside it, it's a hopeless task for instance

```
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f_x(x,y,z) = 0 \\ 
f_y(x,y,z) = 0 \\ 
f_z(x,y,z) = 0\\
\end{matrix}\right. \iff 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 y = 0 \\ 
 x = 0 \\ 
 z = 0\\
 \end{matrix}\right. \iff
 \left\{\begin{matrix}
  y = 0 \\ 
  x = 0 \\ 
 z = \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{matrix}\right.$ I can't write anything here "beside" it because it's just going to get cut off and goes under the system of equations
```

Comment: possible duplicate? see: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-figure)

Comment: @CountZero, link is broken.

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-figure

Comment: I am going to edit my question

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Is there a way to do it without that package?

Comment: @jak do you want the text to wrap and continue below the matrices or do you just need to place some text beside the matrices?

Comment: I guess that the best thing is to put those matrices in a display, that is between `\[` and `\]` rather than `$...$`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, beside the matrices thank you

Comment: @jak please see my answer below. Is it something like that what you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\text` from the `amsmath` package; if required, a `\parbox` can be used to accommodate long texts. As **egreg** mentioned in a comment, instead of using `matrix` and `\left`, `\right.` you can use the `cases` environment from `amsmath`; here's an example showing both possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{\begin{matrix}
f_x(x,y,z) = 0 \\ 
f_y(x,y,z) = 0 \\ 
f_z(x,y,z) = 0
\end{matrix}\right. \iff 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 y = 0 \\ 
 x = 0 \\ 
 z = 0
 \end{matrix}\right. \iff
 \left\{\begin{matrix}
  y = 0 \\ 
  x = 0 \\ 
 z = \frac{1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right.\qquad
\text{\parbox{4cm}{I can write anything here "beside" using a box if necessary}}
\]

\[
\begin{cases}
f_x(x,y,z) = 0 \\ 
f_y(x,y,z) = 0 \\ 
f_z(x,y,z) = 0
\end{cases} \iff 
\begin{cases}
 y = 0 \\ 
 x = 0 \\ 
 z = 0
 \end{cases} \iff
 \begin{cases}
  y = 0 \\ 
  x = 0 \\ 
 z = \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}\quad
\text{\parbox{3.5cm}{I can write anything here "beside" using a box if necessary}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use the `cases` environment, but it's a matter of preferences.

Comment: @egreg I'll add to my answer an example using `cases`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I need. What does the \qquad thing do? The parbox just makes a boxed paragraph I know that.

Comment: Why do things look "bigger" in the cases environment?

Comment: @jak the `cases` environment internally uses `\arraystretch{1.2}` so there's an extra 20% space between rows.

Comment: @jak I forgot your other question: `\qquad` is a double em-quad space (approx. `2em` in the current font); it's the double of `\quad` (approx. `1em` in the current font).

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to do it for \begin{align}...\end{align} as well? I tried applying the same method to that and it didn't work.

Comment: @jak you could use something like `\begin{align}
a &= b \&= c \qquad \text{some text here}\&= d
\end{align}` and `\parbox` if required.

Comment: Yeah that works too, I tried using \hspace{} \text{...} but it kind moves my equation. I tried combining your stuff with \hspace{} and it still moves my equations lol